# Bootstrap not working locally in angular project

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap

Earlier I have been using bootstrap 4 cdn in my angular project. But now I want to use bootstrap 4 from my local sytem. So I installed bootstrap in my angular project. I have been trying this since last 4 days but its not working. This is project [folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAXak.png) structure this is folder where [bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAXak.png) is installed .

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link type="text/css" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/logo.png">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c11cee5f6d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

angular.json (Here I have added location of bootstrap file in styles tag)

```html
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "BhaktivedantaVidyabhavan": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/BhaktivedantaVidyabhavan",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "src/custom-theme.scss"
              },
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "BhaktivedantaVidyabhavan:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "BhaktivedantaVidyabhavan:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "BhaktivedantaVidyabhavan:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "BhaktivedantaVidyabhavan:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "BhaktivedantaVidyabhavan:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "BhaktivedantaVidyabhavan",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "5205b53a-4d06-45fb-9df5-2710122943cd"
  }
}
```

This is what showing error in console
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by its not working?

Comment: I mean, the bootstrap classes which I have used in my template is not working.

Comment: what classes and can you show us an example?